# Strange variable assignment

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I was studying some code I found on the web recently, and came across this php syntax:

```
<?php $framecharset && $frame['charset'] = $framecharset; ?>
```

Can someone explain what is going on in this line of code?
What variable(s) are being assigned what value(s), and what is the purpose of the && operator, in that location of the statement?

Thanks!
Pat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I just wrote a blog post about this idiom in javascript:

http://www.mcphersonindustries.com/

Basically it's testing to see that `$framecharset` exists, and then tries to assign it to `$frame['charset']` if it is non-null.

The way it works is that interpreters are lazy. Both sides of an `&&` statement need to be true to continue. When it encounters a `false` value followed by `&&`, it stops. It doesn't continue evaluating (so in this case the assignment won't occur if `$framecharset` is `false` or `null`).

Some people will even put the more "expensive" half of a boolean expression after the `&&`, so that if the first condition isn't `true`, then the expensive bit won't ever be processed. It's arguable how much this actually might save, but it uses the same principle.

Comment: Alex, what would the exact javascript equivalent syntax look like?

Comment: Oh, I see it on your blog, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` in [`PHP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) is short-circuited, which means the `RHS` will not be evaluated if the `LHS` evaluates to be `false`, because the result will always be `false`.

Your code:

```
$framecharset && $frame['charset'] = $framecharset;
```

is equivalent to :

```
if($framecharset) {
    $frame['charset'] = $framecharset;
}
```

Which assigns the value of `$framecharset` as value to the array key `charset` only if the value evaluates to be `true` and in PHP

> All strings are true except for two: a string ***containing nothing at all*** and a string containing only the ***character 0***