# Using the name of a variable and then defining a function for the variable

Tags: javascript

I've seen this hovering around some javascript for a while now and was wondering what it meant.

In this code:

```
var topics = {};

jQuery.Topic = function( id ) {

    var callbacks,
        topic = id && topics[ id ];
    if ( !topic ) {
        callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();
        topic = {
            publish: callbacks.fire,
            subscribe: callbacks.add,
            unsubscribe: callbacks.remove
        };
        if ( id ) {
            topics[ id ] = topic;
        }
    }
    return topic;
};
```

why does the variable topic have `id &&` before it?

Comment: **See also:**
Strange variable assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640786/strange-variable-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&&` operator results in its first operand if it is "falsy" and to the second operand if the first operand is not "falsy". So, you could read this code as:

> Let topic be `topics[id]` if this function was given a parameter¹, or
>   `undefined` if not.
>
> ¹ Passing `false` or `0` or other falsy values as a parameter would cause `topic` to get
>   that value, but reading the code does not leave the impression that you are supposed to do
>   that.

Comment: Actually it results in the value of the 1st operand if it's "falsy".  `null && 12` returns `null`, not `false`.

Answer (score 1):

What that line is doing is ensuring that `id` is a truthy value before attempting to use it. It's probably not a good idea here, as it would make `topics[0]` inaccessible.

The line `topic = id && topics[id]` is roughly equivalent to `if( id) topic = topics[id]; else topic = id;`

Comment: wait... why would it make topics[0] in accesible?

Comment: Because `0` is falsy, so it would not pass the `&&`.

Comment: @Kolink—worth adding that property names are strings and that `'0'` is truethy, so could result in strange errors: `var id = '0';` will "work", as will `topics[0];` (the number is converted to a string for the sake of property resolution) but `var id = 0` and `0 && topics[0]` wont (for the reasons you pointed out).